# Why can "to" be or not be omitted in the following?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, bare-infinitives

> They acted as if they were mourning him rather than helping him (to) start a new life.
>
> The first step to help him was (to) give him a good education.

You can omit *to* in the first sentence. But you can't in the second sentence.

I know this, but I'm not sure why. I would like to know why.

Note: they're sentences I wrote myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question! When *help* has an object immediately followed by a complement clause, the  *to* is optional:

- Please help me (to) unpack these boxes.

In the second sentence of your question, the *to*-clause is not a complement of *help*, so the *to* is mandatory.

*Let* and *make* only take clausal complements without *to*:

- Let me unpack these boxes.
- Don't make me unpack these boxes.

These patterns have to be learned on a verb-specific basis. *Allow* and *force* have similar meanings but require *to*:

- Allow me to unpack these boxes.
- Don't force me to unpack these boxes.

Comment: Nice post! "These patterns have to be learned on a verb-specific basis" <--- Hmmm. I don't think this is the best advice. The verbs that can take plain form/bare infinitival complements form an absolutely tiny group (*Let, make, help*, verbs of perception, modal verbs. That's it!) So everything else that takes an infinitive takes a *to*-infinitive - which is good to know ... .

Comment: Fair enough. I should have said certain verbs are exceptions—it is not completely predictable from meaning.